# Not showing widgets on 2nd page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is the whole of my code:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import os

def bowlingspeedcalc ():
    if type(mEntry) == float:
        speed = 0.01890*3600/mEntry

        if speed >165:
            tk.Label (str(speed) + " kph !!! You don't bowl that fast!!!o_0 ").place (x = 50,y = 50)                             

        elif speed >=140:
            tk.Label ("You are a fast bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50) 

        elif speed >= 130:
            tk.Label ("You are a fast-medium bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

        elif speed >= 120:
            tk.Label ("You are a medium-fast bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

        elif speed >= 105:
            tk.Label ("You are a medium pace bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

        elif speed < 105 and speed > 60:
            tk.Label ("You are a spin bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

        elif speed <= 60:
            tk.Label ("You bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour; you bowl like my grandma!!!").place (x = 50,y = 50)





def forget_page ():
    widgets = [mlabel1,mlabel2,mlabel3,mEntry,mButton]
    bowlingspeedcalc ()
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.place_forget ()

mGui = tk.Tk()
mGui.geometry("300x300")
mGui.title("YourBowlingSpeed")
mlabel1 = tk.Label (text = "How much time does your ball take to cover the")
mlabel2 = tk.Label (text = "20m/22yrds ,from the release to crossing ")
mlabel3 = tk.Label (text = "the stumps?")
mlabel1.place (x = 20,y = 5)
mlabel2.place (x = 17,y = 22)
mlabel3.place (x = 130,y = 39)
mEntry = tk.Entry()
mEntry.place (x = 115,y = 56)
mButton = tk.Button (text = "Calculate",command = forget_page)
mButton.place (x = 125, y = 73)
```

This is allof my code ... A mbutton's command goes to `forget_page` which goes to `bowlingspeedcalc` but when the program is executed it doesnot show anything on the new page??? Any help would be appreciated.... :D

Comment: It is impossible for us to guess why your code has a bug, without seeing a reproducible case. At the very least, we need to see where you define `mlabel`, `mlabel2`, etc., and the code that creates the 2nd page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls `bowlingspeedcalc`, which attempts to create  some widgets. In the very next line you have a loop to remove all the widgets from the screen.

Also, the first line of `bowlingspeedcalc` compares the type of `mEntry` to float, which will always fail. `mEntry` is a widget, not a number. If you want to get the data that the user entered, you must call the `get`method of that widget. This will always return a string, so you will need to convert it to a number.

Comment: Thanks because i'm new to python where can i find the "get" method please?

Comment: @ShahidIqbal: it's mentioned in probably every tutorial and document related to the tkinter Entry widget. Here's one: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method

Comment: Yes but the get method is for getting a string value so do u know a method for retrieving FLOAT vales from entry boxes?

Comment: @ShahidIqbal: there is no way to get a float value because there is no float value. The widget only supports string values. If you want a float, you can convert it using normal python methods.

Comment: what do you mean by normail python methods?

Comment: @shahidiqbal: The code `int("123")` will convert the string `"123"` to an integer, and `float("123")` will convert it to a float.